# I cant get the contents of a file to print on the console of pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Here is my code for creating a file and printing its contents in the console window of pycharm. The problem is that I can only see blank spaces in that window while the file is successfully created.

```
fw= open('text.txt','w')
fw.write("text is written \n")
fw.write("oh yea \n")
fw.close

fr = open('text.txt', 'r')
print(fr.read())
fr.close()
```

Comment: use `fw.close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the () in close function

```
fw= open('text.txt','w')
fw.write("text is written \n")
fw.write("oh yea \n")
fw.close()

fr = open('text.txt', 'r')
print(fr.read())
fr.close()
```